# How to add a Devanagari character in a math equation?

Tags: equations, hindi, devanagari

I was wondering if it is possible to write a devanangari letter in equation. I tried by using devanagari package but no luck. even setting up Noto Sans Devanagari my main font didn't help.

used all combinations with PDFLaTex, LuaLaTex, XeLaTex.

Comment: if it is set up for text you could use `$1+\text{devanangari  here} + 2$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simplest to use `\text` from `amsmath` and a text font, so using lualatex:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{fontspec,amsmath}

\newfontfamily{\devanagarifont}{Noto Sans Devanagari}[
    Script=Devanagari,
]



\begin{document}

\[
\frac{1+2}{3}+4 =
\frac{\text{\devanagarifont एक}+\text{\devanagarifont दो}}{\text{\devanagarifont तीन}}+\text{\devanagarifont चार}
\]


\end{document}
```